# Is there a Quick Way of Proving this Particular Case of the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I know that [the Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) states that, for every function $f\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the set of its [Lebesgue points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point) is almost all $\mathbb{R}^n$ which means that $f$ is approximately continuous for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The thing is: is there a way of proving the particular case

> **Prop:** If $f\in {\mathcal{L}}^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $\exists x_0\in\mathbb{R}:\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{1}{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^xf(t)d\lambda(t)=f(x_0)$

without explicitly making use of the LDT? Clearly, if $f$ were locally continuous at some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x_0$ would satisfy the desired condition. However, it could so happen that $f$ is nowhere continuous while being Lebesgue integrable, e.g. the Dirichlet function $f=\chi_\mathbb{Q}$. So how could we prove it in general without the said theorem? Thanks :)

Comment: If $f \in L^1( \mathbb R)$ I don't know what is $f(x_0)$...

Comment: @blamethelag, I meant $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$. That is, the set of Lebesgue integrable functions without identifying the ones that are equal almost everywhere. I've already changed it.

Comment: @blamethelag It's an extremely common abuse of notations anyways. $f\in L^1$ often stands for, "$f$ is integrable"